# Orthogonal matrix sufficient proof

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

To show that a square matrix $F$ is orthogonal, is it sufficient to show that  $F^TF = I$ or is it also necessary to show $\det(F)= \pm1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to show a square matrix $A$ is orthogonal is $A^T A = I$ (or equivalently, $A A^T = I$ or also equivalently, $A^{-1} = A^T$).

The fact that $det(A) = \pm 1$ follows from this, since $det(A^T A) = det(A^T) det(A) = det(A) det(A) = det(A)^2$ and $det(I) = 1$. So, $det(A)^2 = 1$ or $det(A) = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to show that $det(F) = \pm1$

Square matrix $F$ is orthogonal if 
 $$F^{-1} = F^T$$

But we know
$$
F^T \cdot F  = I
$$

And

$$
F^{-1} \cdot F = I
$$
So

$$
F^T \cdot F  = I
$$
$$
(F^T \cdot F)\cdot F^{-1}  = (I)\cdot F^{-1}
$$
$$
F^T\cdot(F\cdot F^{-1})  = F^{-1}
$$
$$
F^T\cdot(I)  = F^{-1}
$$
$$
F^T = F^{-1}
$$